# Read Excel file from a set index

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Is it possible to read a file from a set column "eg `A2`" and read the whole document?

Current code:

```
("Select  * FROM [" + excelSheet[i] + "]", excelConnection);
```

Comment: you want to read data from a single column of Excel?

Comment: no starting at the column and row index and the rest of the file

Comment: i think you want to read the excel file

Comment: i want to start reading the excel file at row 2 and all of the columns that point and below

Answer (score 0):

Specify your column names as you would any SQL query. Using * gets all the columns. Specifying the individual set of columns retrieves just those. As for starting at the row you want, after  you get the data, you can simply use LINQ and the `Skip()` method to start at a specific "row".

**EXAMPLE: Using your code above**

```
("Select  A,B,C,D FROM [" + excelSheet[i] + "]", excelConnection);
```

I cannot give you any further example based on your code as far as iterating over the collection. So here's a sample demonstrating the concept..

NOTE: I am using the ACE.OLEDB driver not jet and is parsing for CSV. See www.connectionstrings.com for examples of connstrings that use EXCEL; but I imagine you already have one which you can swap out.

```
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        var connStr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""{0}"";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited"";", dir);

        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(@"Select A,B,C,D from {0}", fileName), conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            IDataReader records = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            var result = YOURLOGICTOMAPRECORDSET_TOLIST();
            var filteredSet=result.Skip([ROWCOUNTTOSKIPHERE]).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: this wont take into consideration multiple sheets.. also does not start from the second row oif the file

Comment: YOU have make the row start happen by supplying that value in the skip. If you want to read multiple sheets, you need to run this on all the sheets. You could replace the result variable by filling a dataset for neatly contained set of data as you run each sheet and then you have an in memory representation of each sheet for which you can iterate over, start at whatever row you want etc.. etc..